# javascript: The best way to switch two strings depending on a counter whether it is odd or even

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

If you want to have a set of `1;0;1;0;...`  for increasing counter, you use `%2`:

```
1%2=1; 2%2=0; 3%2=1; 4%2=0;...
```

What's the best way to have changing `"yes";"no";"yes";"no";...` in the same manner?

I don't care about the language, whether it is javascript or c#. I need an idea. Anything's better than using an array that consists of two strings?

Comment: *"Anything's better than using an array that consists of two strings?"* That's not necessarily a bad approach at all. Not the first thing that comes to mind, but not necessarily *bad*.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch"? Just choose between, or...?

Comment: By "switch" I mean changing by increasing a counter. Let's say "yes" for odd values of counter and "no" for even values of counter variable.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Do you mean choosing between them? Or do you have two variables referencing strings and want to swap their values? Or....?

Comment: I mean choosing between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your counter logic. In C-ish:

```
((counter % 2) == 0) ? "No" : "Yes"
```

I know you said "anything is better than an array..." but I also like this - to select element 0 or 1 in an array:

```
arr[counter % 2]
```

Comment: *"In C-ish"* Assuming that's the right hand of an assignment or similar, that's fine for C# and JavaScript as well. (Or any other language syntactically derived from B...)

Comment: What about (counter%2) ? "yes" : "no", so it is even shorter? At least for js. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, My be you could use some thing like

bool bChangeValue;
bChangeValue = !bChangeVales;
This will allways be true;false;true;false..

Comment: Right, for 0 and 1 we use %2, for true-false we use ! sign. Good point! But what about strings "yes", "no"?